Can't access C:\Program Files\WindowsApps Directory
While I was trying to evaluate if Python 3.11 was installed on my system, I decided to look into the dir C:\Program Files\WindowsApps to have a look, but Windows says I don't have permission despite that I am logged in as admin.

When I click on on the link to the Security Tab and open the Advanced button, I am brought to 'Advanced Security Settings for WindowsApps':

When I click on the continue button a list of permissions is shown for each user:

As shown in the screenshot, my admin user account already shows that I have Read & Write permissions for this directory.
What settings, if any, do I need to change in Windows to get access to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps ?
Running Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Take a look this article

This question is similar to: What is WindowsApp folder for?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


The WindowsApps folder, as we’ve mentioned, is a restricted folder
containing Microsoft Store apps. It also contains some Windows apps
that use the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app style (as introduced
in Windows 8), such as the Your Phone app (yourphone.exe). From a
security point of view, restricting the WindowsApps folder makes
sense. By sandboxing Microsoft Store apps from the rest of Windows,
and limiting ownership of the files to a hidden TrustedInstaller user
account, Microsoft Store apps have limited access to the rest of
Windows compared to standard desktop apps.

For security reasons even the administrator account doesn't have permission for accessing such folder. Then, it doesn't make any sense to change the permission of the WindowsApps folder.
Source: How to Access the Windowsapps Folder in Windows 10

Why does it say then that I have Read & Write permissions?

@KalamalkaKid Likely Read and Execute to be able to execute Windows Apps, Write to be able to save data within an app's respective folder (such as settings for the app)

Read and Execute isn’t write permissions.
